# Android OpenGL ES2 crashes when using integers

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

I've tried http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es20.html and it works but when I replace floats with ints with `GL_INT` as well, it crashes instead. Do integers simply not work?

Comment: could you be more specific please? Which floats do you just replace with integers? And more important: Why do you replace them?

Comment: The triangleCoords for the triangleVB. I'm testing things out.

Comment: Coordinates should be floats. You can't change the type of a value and expect that it will work like before... Also a bit more code should be posted...

Comment: OpenGL ES2 is supposed to work with integers as well as floats.

Comment: Please provide a code sample. Specifically where you load the vertex buffers or VBOs as well as where you draw. Also providing the crash log will help.

Comment: Until you post some code, we can only assume what you changed, and how and we just have to assume the worst!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just replace the integers with floats and forget about it. I'm just confused why it wont allow integers.